# Dropdown menu to display large content

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have alot of information under some items in my website page and I want to make it look better by using dropdowns to display the content when the user clicks on the item, is it possibe using HTML & CSS only? 
-like that ones when using wikipedia on mobile devices-

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow, you may need to provide more information so that we can help you. I am not sure I understand, but I'll assume you need to do a dropdown menu, then yes, it is doable using HTML and CSS only.

Comment: @AhmedHammad Hi, It is not a regular dropdown menu if I can say so, it doesn't display a list of links or a simple list of info, I tried to upload  an image of what I meant but I couldn't..

Comment: Hi, welcome! You may need to provide more information so that we can help you. Can you be more specific? What does it mean 'I have alot of information under some items in my website page'? Can you show us your code?